# How to get IIS to accept-encoding: gzip(gfe)

Tags: iis, rewrite, page-speed

Google's PageSpeed Service forwards requests with the `accept-encoding` header set to `gzip(gfe)`. Unfortunately IIS chokes on this with the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Fri, 11 Apr 2014 02:19:39 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 311
```

Here's the full request:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost/stream/tags HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip(gfe)
Content-Length: 0
```

HTTPERR log just lists `400 Bad Request` with no additional fields.

I've experimented with changing this value using URL rewrite module:

```
  <rule name="Accept Encoding Rewrite PageSpeed" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern="gfe" />
    </conditions>
    <serverVariables>
      <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="gzip" />
    </serverVariables>
    <action type="None" />
  </rule>
```

But I'm affraid that the rewrite rules are running after whatever generates the 400.

And also with `AllowWeakHeaderValueSyntax` mentioned at http://forums.iis.net/p/1176719/1976075.aspx

Any ideas for how to remap accept-encoding to `gzip` without using another appliance?

Comment: What does the `HTTPERR` log entry say for these failed requests? Can you post the full request header, too?

Comment: @EvanAnderson updated, not much there, unfortunately.